# How do I make dropdown list items display on top of the row that contains them?

Tags: bootstrap-4

In the html below I have a dropdown within a row. The row height is 3.7rem. When I click on the dropdown the list items are not visible because the row height is not large enough. They are hidden behind the row. I gave the dropdown z-index:1 but this did not solve the problem.

```
<div class="row nav-bar bg-secondary-blue mt-2" style="height: 3.7rem;">
<div class="col">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="dropdown offset-2">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#" 
                class="dropdown-toggle nav-link dropdown-toggle dropbtn w-15 mt-1">
                Departments
            </a>
            <div role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" style="z-index:1;">
                <a role="presentation" href="#" class="dropdown-item c-black">
                    First Item
                </a>
                <a role="presentation" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                    Second Item
                </a>
                <a role="presentation" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                    Third Item
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using the latest Bootstrap 4? What is the row contained in? I can't repro the issue with the code posted.

Comment: I am using the latest bootstrap. The row is contained within a container.

Comment: I can't repro it: https://www.codeply.com/go/Jateez3FLy -- the dropdown appears as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what your issue might be. I tried your code with just the Bootstrap CSS file, and the issue replicated as you said, with the dropdown cut off by the row. So I then added the Bootstrap JS files, and the dropdown works fine. Have you included your Bootstrap JS files?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row nav-bar bg-secondary-blue mt-2" style="height: 3.7rem;">
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="dropdown offset-2">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link dropdown-toggle dropbtn w-15 mt-1">
                Departments
            </a>
          <div role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" style="z-index:1;">
            <a role="presentation" href="#" class="dropdown-item c-black">
                    First Item
                </a>
            <a role="presentation" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                    Second Item
                </a>
            <a role="presentation" href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                    Third Item
                </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I am using Bootstrap Studio to design my page. It comes with bootstrap 4.1 installed.